# persistent network interface naming and kvm

Tags: udev, kvm, qemu, network-interface

I wonder why my network interface is still named `eth0` in my kvm guests. udevadm just outputs

```
# udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/eth0 2> /dev/null
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enxc2184ae7ab3f
```

I would expect them to be called like `enpXsY`. The directory `/etc/udev/rules.d` is empty. The Linux brand is Gentoo, 3.15.5-hardened-r2. Virtualization is KVM with qemu 2.0, the net interface is virtio. On the host and on other machines the setup is the same w.r.t. udev but the interfaces are called by their new names as expected.

Why is this so?  What would it need to enable the new identifiers?

My first thought was that the new identifiers refer to PCI devices, and that virtio devices are not PCI devices.  However, `lspci` proved me wrong:

```
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio network device
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc Device 0001
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at c040 [size=32]
    Memory at febd1000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at feb80000 [disabled] [size=256K]
    Capabilities: [40] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=3 Masked-
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci

00:04.0 SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc Virtio block device
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc Device 0002
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10                                    
    I/O ports at c000 [size=64]
    Memory at febd2000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=2 Masked-
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci
```

So that's not the reason.

Comment: Is this even a question? Or is it an observation?

Comment: no, this is a question.

Comment: It is called `eth0` because there is no `udev` rule for renaming it. `eth0` is the kernel name - it is the kernel's first ethernet slot. Create a `udev` rule for renaming the if or copy one from the other installations.